# Loop that increments iteration but avoids the overlap of my output in javascript

Tags: javascript

New to javascript
I need a loop that will increment each iteration by 1, but as it is now, I am getting the same number twice (once as a new 'end' and then again as a new 'start)

I tried using an array and I think that might be better but I can't get it to work

```
var start='20190100'
var end='20190101'
var limit='20190131'

while (start <= limit) {
    start++, end++;
    var date_range=start.toString()+","+end.toString();
    console.log(date_range)
}
```

This is my output now;

```
'20190101,20190102'
'20190102,20190103' 
'20190103,20190104'
```

But i need for it to be;

```
'20190101,20190102'
'20190103,20190104'
```

Comment: Why are you manipulating strings as numbers instead of dates?

Comment: why you need another variable `end` when you just want +1?

Comment: because I could not get an array that took both 20190101 and 20190102 to work, so I tried working it out another way 
@phuzi because this is the way that the reporting system takes in the dates, as a string and in that order

Comment: its just `x` and `x+1`, why you need an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just increment them both by 2 instead of 1:

```js
var start = 20190100
var end = 20190101
var limit = 20190131

while (start <= limit) {
  var date_range = start + "," + end;
  console.log(date_range)
  start += 2;
  end += 2;
}
```

Or use a single variable:

```js
var start = 20190100
var limit = 20190131

while (start <= limit) {
  var date_range = start + "," + (start + 1);
  console.log(date_range)
  start += 2;
}
```

Comment: Oh fantastic, the second one worked like a charm. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can increment it once more at the end of the iteration

```js
var start='20190100'
var end='20190101'
var limit='20190131'

while (start <= limit) {
    ++start, ++end;
    var date_range=start.toString()+","+end.toString();
 start++; end++
    console.log(date_range)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem with increment the variable by 2 in each iteration?

```
start += 2;
end   += 2;
```